# How many lightsabers could be made from the Death Star's crystals?

Tags: star-wars, kyber-crystal

The Death Star's weapon was made with kyber crystals, the same material used to make lightsabers.

**How many lightsabers could be made with the quantity of kyber crystals that were used to create the Death Star I?**

[image]

Comment: Enough to make at least a dozen sequels...

Comment: Just one, but it would be really big.

Comment: @RichS - The size of a small moon?

Comment: @Valorum No, a space station.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The first Death Star contained multiple large kyber crystals. We can see what they look like in this still from the unfinished episode [Star wars: Clone Wars - In Search of the Crystal](http://www.starwars.com/video/star-wars-the-clone-wars-story-reel-in-search-of-the-crystal)

[image]

Assuming it has 8 in total (one for [each energy beam](https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/5/50/Superlaser2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111104205236)) and that they're each as large as the one that Obi-Wan and Anakin intercepted (about 6ft x 4ft x 4ft), we can make some calculations.

---

A kyber crystal shard needs to be [about 1 inch x 1/3 inch x 1/3 inch](http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/06/ezra-kyber-crystal-2-1536x864-295422017620.jpeg) to use in a lightsaber or approximately 0.00000147 cubic meters. Assuming the larger crystals can be subdivided into individual crystals without losing much material, the answer is that a crystal that's 2.7 cubic meters could make around 1.8 million lightsabers.

Multiplied by eight, **you could make something like 14 million lightsabers from the crystals used in the Death Star I.**

[image]

http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/06/ezra-kyber-crystal-2-1536x864-295422017620.jpeg

Comment: Thank you and +1 for answering at the level on which the question was asked. I have long been curious about this question. I do not know why others down voted the OP.

Comment: @CodeMed - It's the sort of question that can seem (to the *untrained eye*) unanswerable and slightly nonsensical. Luckily, the nice people at LucasFilm have given us more than enough technical detail to answer these sorts of questions.

Comment: I estimate about 1.3 million light sabers based on 1728 cubic inches per cubic foot times 96 cubic feet per beam times 8 beams. I I imagine that you are using less than a cubic inch per light saber. But not 500 times less. ... In any event, I just wanted to know the rough magnitude of this imprecise comparison, and you showed the rough scale difference.

Comment: @CodeMed - Oops yes, obvs. I've recalculated and put everything into the same scale.

Comment: @CodeMed - Note that the downvotes have been dramatically outweighed now. Don't be disheartened by the occasional nay-sayer. Keep asking quality questions and you'll get plenty of +1's

Comment: Deduct probably around a million lightsabers due to packing efficiency and/or wastage issues.

Comment: @aroth - If your men are having problems cutting that crystal, perhaps I can find *new ways to motivate them...*