# Did the Death Star's crystals "speak"?

Tags: star-wars, kyber-crystal

The official [Star Wars](http://www.starwars.com/databank/lightsaber) website explains that  lightsabers are made of kyber crystals that are inextricably linked to the Jedi who makes the light saber. In fact, the kyber crystal even "speaks" to the Jedi, instructing the Jedi to choose the specific crystal for use in the specific Jedi's lightaber.

The Death Star's weapon is made from kyber crystals large enough to make [over a million](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165411/how-many-lightsabers-could-be-made-from-the-death-stars-crystals)  lightsabers.

**Is there any evidence that these massive kyber crystals spoke to the people who envisioned the creation of the Death Star?**

Comment: *Rogue One: Catalyst* ;)

Comment: aren't they artificial crystals at Death Star?

Comment: @Oni "Kyber crystals were used as part of the Death Star's superlaser, and Galen Erso was brought on as the main researcher under Project Celestial Power. Kyber crystals were looted from Jedi lightsabers, temples, Ilum, and other worlds where they could be found."  https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal

Comment: @Oni Related: https://starwars.fandom.com/f/p/3100000000000096305

Comment: @Oni "While kyber crystals are at the core of every lightsaber, the Empire explored ways to weaponize them for more nefarious purposes. They began to mine for kyber crystals across worlds, and were notably thwarted twice in securing massive crystals by the Ghost crew and Saw Gerrera. But on Jedha they uncovered a surplus of kyber, which would be enough to power their dreaded Death Star." https://www.starwars.com/databank/lightsaber-crystal

Comment: Interesting: https://spoiledbluemilk.com/2016/06/15/a-brief-history-of-kyber-crystals/