# Is there a shortage of Kyber crystals in the galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, kyber-crystal

Given Kyber crystals are used to make the Death Star laser in *A New Hope*, *Return of the Jedi* and I am guessing *The Force Awakens* and they are also a necessary constituent of a Jedi's lightsaber, is there now a shortage of Kyber crystals in the Galaxy?

Comment: when is "now"? Do you mean post Force Awakens? Also - prior to TFA, it would depend on which side of the war you are on. In other words, the guy hoarding everything doesn't think there is a shortage at all ;)

Comment: It's only a shortage if there's a demand for them. Jedi are pretty much gone, so they don't need them.

Comment: I'd think that the fact that people keep on using them means that there is no shortage. You never hear people say "aww, I wish we had more kyber crystals". On the other hand, Luke definitely had a shortage of power converters.

Comment: Only the strongest stars have hearts of kyber.

Comment: So the Death Star superlasers used really big kyber crystals? There's no shortage around the place where the Death Star blew up. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165411/how-many-lightsabers-could-be-made-from-the-death-stars-crystals

Comment: There is no mention of Kyber crystals being used in SW:TFA. The super weapon is powered by converting solar energy. On the other hand, the "LEGO Star Wars: Freemaker Adventures" TV show (which is not canon, but does avoid contradicting canon) just did some episodes where the Empire is in the middle of building the 2nd Death Star and is having a hard time finding Kyber crystals to power the super laser. So, in that universe, at least, Kyber crystals in any large quantity have become very rare indeed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Converting solar energy... and channeling it through Kyber crystals. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112601/did-starkiller-base-use-kyber-crystals?rq=1  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/180433/2171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use the word "shortage" but something more in the way of "monopoly".

Why ? Because like JBH said in his answer, Kyber crytals were already rare in the Star Wars universe, add to the equation that each reigning power in the galaxy claimed exclusive rights of those and you obtain something rare, hard to come across but not impossible to obtain.

Be it during the time of the **[Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal)** :

> Over the centuries, the Jedi amassed an almost exclusive right to the crystals, protecting and collecting them to decorate their temples and power their lightsabers.

During the **[Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedha)** :

> Sometime after the fall of the Jedi Order and the Galactic Republic, its successor state—the Galactic Empire—occupied Jedha in order to mine its kyber crystal deposits. Unknown to all but the most high-ranking officials in the Empire, the crystals were being used as components in the construction of an Imperial superlaser capable of destroying entire planets.

And even by the last in date, the **First Order** :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A shortage can only be declared in context of supply and demand. A material can be quite rare and yet, due to limited demand, not be in a state of "shortage."

From a story-telling POV, Kyber wants to be a fairly rare element.  It won't be found on just any old planet.  Were it common, every Tom, Dick, and Clone 99 would be building their own lightsabers. They'd be available on every street corner. So, is there a shortage? I don't know.  Are they rare? Absolutely. Would that make them hard to come by? Yup.

Comment: I doubt the kyber was the only limiting factor in lightsaber construction. Rather, access to the information in general was probably closely guarded, as well as we have canon evidence that construction requires Force abilities

Comment: Point well taken, but the OP's question was specifically about Kyber, which the SW universe identifies as a critical resource for light sabers.

Comment: ....right, and your answer made that case that kyber is rare because otherwise people would be making lightsabers left and right. I disagree that kyber availability is a sticking point for lightsaber creation when there are other broader abilities / knowledge required before even getting to that point :)